# Automatically modify primitive based on texture

Tags: mesh

I have a cube with black and white squares on its surface (texture). Like this:
[image: Textured cube]

My question is: How can I reshape this cube in a way, that the black parts stick out? I could modify it manually with edge/face loops, but what if I have hundreds of black squares? That would take me days. There must be some automated method.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you looked into using the displacement modifier? With that you could control the high offset with a texture.

Comment: @Jackdaw i actually did the same experiment and it looks ugly...

Answer (score 1):

### Array modifier

As long as the pattern is repeated in a Grid, you can replicate "N" times a mesh along the main axis with the Array modifier:

[image]

For your particular case, you'll have to build a mesh made by 3 cubes and stack one Array modifier for each axis, adjusting the Relative offset vector:

[image]

[image]

Comment: he didnt mean this

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted. It works if my texture is periodic, but what if it isn't? What if some squares are randomly missing?Or my primitive is not a cube but a cylinder or a cone? In these cases your solution won't work.

Comment: If the texture you have in mind is not periodic, it would be quite hard to automate the process, as probably depends on what the texture actually looks like and the rules behind its generation. I succest to change the example in your question in order to reflect what you are actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

I assume you have your cube mesh already UV unwrapped. If you haven't done this yet do it prior to following the rest of this.

Select your cube and go to the Modifiers tab. Apply a Subdivivsion Surface modifier on your cube mesh. Choose the "Simple" subdivision option, then set the view and/or render multipliers as high as you want (the higher the number the sharper the protrusions would be but the more intensive the scene would be on your computer, don't push it too far or Blender or your computer may crash).

Next add a Displace modifier to the cube. Choose the checkered texture of the object from the drop-down menu and then mess around with the midlevel and strength modifiers until you get the desired effect. I'd suggest setting midlevel to zero.

Oh and (if it's necessary) specify the UV map of your object in the little Texture Coordinates part of the modifier by choosing the "UV" option from the dropdown box and choosing your UV map.